# WP8 Pivot Overlapped When Changed Binding Source

Tags: pivot, windows-phone-8

I found a problem when i use the pivot control in the `Windows Phone 8 SDK`.

The pivot binds to a list named `Students` and set a button when click it，Will new a new student object and set it to `Students[2]` as new value. This has lead to the overlapping problem shown in the screenshot below. Has anyone else had this problem in the `WP8 SDK`?

Here is the code

```
  public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
        //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        InitiList();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = 2;
        Students[index] = new Student();
        Students[index].Name = "tian";
        Students[index].College = "shida";
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Student> _students;
    public ObservableCollection<Student> Students
    {
        get { return _students; }
        set
        {
            _students = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Students");
        }
    }

    private void InitiList()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student { Name="a",College="aa"});
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "b", College = "aa" });
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "c", College = "aa" });
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "d", College = "aa" });
        Students.Add(new Student { Name = "e", College = "aa" });
    }
```

Ckeck this o/p image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're modifying Students but RaisePropertyChanged isn't getting fired because accessing Students doesn't fire Set, which calls RaisePropertyChanged.  This could be the problem, I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same issue, and I fixed it by adding the items to the ObservableCollection in the constructor instead of using the Add method. It appears to be a bug with the ObservableCollection class. Try changing your code to:

```
 private void InitiList()
{
    Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>(new [] {
    new Student { Name="a",College="aa"}),
    new Student { Name = "b", College = "aa" }),
    new Student { Name = "c", College = "aa" }),
    new Student { Name = "d", College = "aa" }),
    new Student { Name = "e", College = "aa" })
    });
}
```